# Projection matrix from Fundamental matrix

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have obtained fundamental matrix between two cameras. I also, have their internal parameters in a `3 X 3` matrix which I had obtained earlier through chess board. Using the fundamental matrix, I have obtained `P1` and `P2` by

`P1 = [I | 0]` and `P2 = [ [e']x * F | e']`

These projection matrices are not really useful in getting the exact 3D location.
Since, I have the internal parameters `K1` and `K2`, I changed `P1` and `P2` as

`P1 = K1 * [I | 0]` and `P2 = K2 * [ [e']x * F | e']`

- Is this the right way to get the real projection matrices which gives the actual relation between the 3D world and the image?
- If not, please help me understand the right way and where I have gone wrong.
- If this is the right approach, how do I verify these matrices?

Answer (score 15):

A good reference book is "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" from Hartley and Zisserman.
First, your formula for P is wrong. If you want the formula with K inside, it is rather

```
P = K * [R | t]
```

or

```
P = [ [e']x * F | e']
```

but not a mix of both.

If you computed F from the 8 points algorithm, then you can recover only projective geometry up to a 3D homography (i.e. a 4x4 transformation).

To upgrade to euclidian space, there are 2 possibilities, both starting by computing the essential matrix.

First possibility is to compute the essential matrix from F: E = transpose(K2)*F*K1.

Second possibility, is to estimate directly the essential matrix for these 2 views:

- Normalize your 2D points by pre multiplying with inverse of K for each image ("normalized image coordinates")
- Apply the (same than for F) 8 points algorithm on these normalized points
- Enforce the fact that the essential matrix has its 2 singular values equal to 1 and last is 0, by SVD decomposition and forcing the diagonal values.

Once you have the essential matrix, we can compute the projection matrix in the form

```
P = K * [R | t]
```

R and t can be found thanks to the elements of the SVD of E (cf the previously mentioned book).
However, you will have 4 possibilities. Only one of them projects points in front of both cameras, so you shall test a point (if you are sure of it) to remove the ambiguity among the 4.
And in this case you will be able to place the camera and its orientation (with R and t of the projection) in your 3D scene.

Not so obvious, indeed...

Comment: What if you don't have the camera parameters K1, K2?

Comment: Then you have to compute the fundamental matrix F

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question and want to give a more direct answer to the question.

When `P1 = [I, 0]` is your first projection matrix but it should be `P1 = K1 * [I, 0]`, then your "world" is distorted by the 4x4 matrix `M = [K1, 0; 0, 1]`.  Any point `X` in the world projects to `x1 = P1 * X = (P1 * M) * (M^-1 * X) = P1' * X'` where `X'` is now the point in the "undistorted world" (note that `X = M * X'` is again the point in the "distorted world") and `P1' = P1 * M = [I, 0] * [K1, 0; 0, 1] = K1 * [I, 0]` is the projection matrix in the undistorted world.

Analoguously, `P2' = P1 * M` is the projection matrix in the undistorted world and has the form `P2' = [ [e']x * F | e'] * [K1, 0; 0, 1] = [ [e']x * F * K1 | e']`.

Note that `P2 = [ [e']x * F | e']` is just one possible projection matrix but in general has the form `P2 = [ [e']x * F + e' * v^T | s * e']` for some real `s` and a 3-vector `v`.  Note further, that if you want to find a projection matrix of the form `P2' ~ K2 * [R, t]` for some rotation matrix `R`, you might be better off using the algorithm based on the essential matrix outlined by Damien and described in Hartley&Zisserman(2.Ed) Sec. 9.6.2.