# Calculating transformation of an object in an image using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection, object-detection

I have two images.

Say one is a 10x10 which we call `trainImage` and then there is another `queryImage` which is the same chessboard photographed using a phone camera. Now I have to find the position of camera in (x,y,z) coordinates. Using openCV and feature detection I have been able to identify the chessboard object in photographed object, but how to go ahead with calculating the transformations on chessboard so that I can eventually calculate the position of camera. Any pointers to start looking upon will also be really appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

Reframing the problem statement again, I have two images `trainImage` and `queryImage`. I need to find the position of camera i.e. (x,y,z) if we assume that `trainImage` is at (0,0,0) in `queryImage`. I did some reading to find this I need `rvec`(rotation vector) and `tvec`(translation vector).

When I use `findHomography()` function on two images I get a 3x3 homgraphy matrix using which I can find the pixels points(x,y) in `queryImage` by multiplying to pixel points(x,y) in `trainImage`. How can I use this `homographyMatrix` for calculating `tvec` and `rvec`.

Comment: Since you have the object detected, you can try **homography**

Comment: @JeruLuke: I have added my latest findings. Please have a look.

Comment: I've recently answered a comment about something else, but down the lines of what you're asking. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538914/why-is-ransac-not-working-for-my-code/42546940#42546940) as a starting point.